# How to implement several versions of a method in java

Tags: java, interface

I am unsure about the correct naming and basically only need a tip on what to search for.

My problem is as follows: I have programmed a small balloon game in java where you steer a hot air balloon. Anyway, I have a class which holds the current position and velocity of the balloon.

Velocity and position get updated at regular intervals using a physics model. I would like to implement different types of physics models that I can switch between during the game. For instance, with/without air friction. So basically I will have different methods that calculate the new position and new velocity after a small timestep.

My question now is, what is the most elegant way to implement this, without making a mess?

My idea would be to have an interface that defines the general structure. An then have implementations of the various physics models.

Is this a good idea? Does this have a name that I could search for?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern could make sense here. You would implement the different calculation algorithms as strategy, and select the proper strategy during runtime, depending on the criteria.

Comment: This might be better suited for other SO sites e.g. code review or software engineering. If you are going to change model mid-flight, then you probably have to pass the model as a parameter to your move() method

Comment: @DavidBrossard It doesn't look like this is ready for code review because it seems that the code isn't implemented fully. See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Yes an interface is what you want. It will make it easy for you to swap between different implementations

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ yup thanks for the links